# Cake 3.0 Cache Configuration for OPcache and APCu

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3.0 what is the right way to configure Cache based on cake built-in caching engines?

I'm using PHP 5.6 with Zend OPcache And APCu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Opcache is a built in opcode cache, it isn't something you need to configure, APCu however will need to be compiled against your webserver and enabled with APC emulation

in `config/app.php` you need to enter the following:

```
   // Using a fully namespaced name.
    'long' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\ApcEngine',
        'duration' => '+1 week',
        'probability' => 100,
        'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
    ]
```

You can create different configs for different cache times.

Then to cache an object you simply:

```
$data = Cache::remember('my_cache_key', function () {
    return Service::expensiveCall();
});
```

Or use the functions `Cache::read` and `Cache::write`